# Is it possible to add an Application to a security group in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to manage users in an application using Microsoft.Graph. I've searched a lot but I don't see another alternative than creating a Security Group, connecting it with my application and add/remove members from this group.

So, as in title, is it possible to assign a Security Group to an App in Azure's Active Directory via Microsoft.Graph?

Comment: You mean to add the app as an owner to the group? Or a member?

Comment: I meant assigning group to an App.

Comment: You can assign apps to an app. That's what appRoles aka application permissions are for.